# Obj-C: UIImageview in Tableviewcell keep reappearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

i am working on an iphone project that shows an artwork at the top tableview section (section 0) and shows a list of items in (section 1). the tableview looks like that:

section0:

ARTWORK IMAGE

section1:

cell1: text1

cell2: text2

.
  .
  . and so goe like that.

but strangely the program shows another imageview at the bottom of the page when i scroll down, but it shouldnt show that image because its not section 0.

heres the code for my program :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        return [diskArray count];
        break;
    default:
        return 0;
        break;
}
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        return 225;
        break;
    default:
        return 44;
        break;
}

}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
// Configure the cell...
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
    NSLog(@"adding image to the cell");
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"artwork.jpeg"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 225, 225)];
    imgView.image = img;
    [cell addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    }
}
else if(indexPath.section == 1){
    cell.textLabel.text = [diskArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: also it looks like this causes random app crashes.. (EXC_BADACCESS) after fixing this bug it stopped crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone reuses old cells with the subview you've added. Try changing the CellIdentifier for each section.

Comment: Thanx i've addd code to dynamically adjust cellIdentifier for each section. its now working without any problem.

Comment: Well, this way you don't mix up the cells, but you still add a new imgView to the first cell each time it appears

Answer (score 0):

It's because you reuse the cell, but nowhere it is reinitialized.
try this to remove the image :

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
} else {
    [cell subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    //you should also reinit the other values, as textLabel, bgColor et al.
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i think philipp's answer looks easier ;)